# Pine-script plotting stepline without the vertical connecting lines

Tags: pine-script

Is there a way in pine script to plot a stepline but without the vertical line connecting two different data point?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please show the code where you are specifically having the issue so someone can help you directly.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it is like this, but it will create multi-bar gaps when changes occur consecutively:

```
//@version=4
study("", "", true)
hi = highest(15)
hiNotChanged = change(hi) == 0
plot(hi, "hi", hiNotChanged ? color.green : na, 6)
```

[image]